# Why is Performance.navigation.type == 1 getting called even if I don't click on refresh button

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am using performance.navigation.type == 1 to know whether the page is being refreshed or not by the user. And if it is refreshed then I want it to go back to previous page.

The code works fine for the first time and the user is taken back to previous page if clicked on refresh button. However, again if user clicks on a link to go to second page, and does not press a refresh button then also performance.navigation.type == 1 is triggered and user is taken back to previous page.

Why is this happening and is there any way to prevent this?

Here's my code written inside the controller:

```
if (performance.navigation.type == 1) {
      window.history.back();
}
```

Comment: Can't repro https://plnkr.co/edit/uKg4rcc8HGw8siOvttgX?p=preview